# Black screen when I open a youtube video on windows 10 1803 education (Nvidia Drivers)

Tags: windows, drivers, nvidia

i own a gtx 970 msi after installing the latest nvidia driver it happens that my screen goes black as soon as i open a video on youtube for a second, but then it goes back to normal and doesn't do it on the other videos anymore. It happens again only if I close the browser and reopen a video on youtube or similar again. What can it depend on? from the driver Nvidia?

Comment: Uninstall the newer driver and install the previous version. See if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Also try updating BIOS, and then update Windows after that. V1803 is getting quite old.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest first trying disabling the hardware acceleration if your system has a graphic card. Then try to play youtube videos on another browser, if the issue is still there try to update your driver or reinstall the driver to solve the issue.